# ListView.Sort() not working correctly with IComparer C#

Tags: c#, listview, icomparer

Within my code, I have a ListView called allocations which stores the location name and the picking priority as its columns. At the moment, it looks something like this:-

```
|    Location    |    Picking Priority    |
|----------------|------------------------|
|   Location A   |          1000          |
|   Location B   |          750           |
|   Location C   |          1000          |
```

I am attempting to use an IComparer to sort by the picking priority so that the location with the lowest picking priority is at the top of the list and the rest follow in ascending order. Currently, this is the code I have:-

```
public ArrayList getSortedListView()
{
    ListView lvLocations = new ListView();
    lvLocations.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();

    // Reads CSV file to get required location. 
    // lvGlobalLocations is filled with every location on the system.

    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvGlobalLocations.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == <location name>)
        {
            lvLocations.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
            lvLocations.Sort();
        }
    }

    // Cycles through ListView and stores location names in ArrayList to be returned.
}


class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi1 = (ListViewItem)a;
        ListViewItem lvi2 = (ListViewItem)b;
        int int1 = int.Parse(lvi1.SubItems[1].Text);
        int int2 = int.Parse(lvi2.SubItems[1].Text);
        if (int1 > int2)
            return -1;
        else if (int1 < int2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I get it to compare correctly so that the ArrayList returned is in the correct order?

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, ever.  Use `List<T>` whenever you need a list.

Comment: @TimRogers sorry, it appears to not sort the list at all. The resulting arraylist is in the same order as it was before.

Comment: To @Servy s point, you have a generic collection to use that will ensure you are type safe and it easier to manage. ArrayList is not type safe and will give you problems with readability of your code and cause bugs when you re-use your code.

Comment: @ChrisGraves it is because you are in fact not even using your comparitor. As noted in my answer you do not actually need it, however if you want to use it the comparitor needs to be passed into the sort.

Comment: @N_tro_P It wont allow me to pass anything into the sort.

Comment: @ChrisGraves can you work on the data independently of the view then populate the view? The sort method I am looking at is for the data containers (i.e. List) not the view. Will have to review the views sort methodology to see what is happening. But either way, you are not using your comparitor as is.

Comment: @chris there is a `ListViewItemSorter` property on `ListView` have you tried to assign your IComparer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above you should ***never*** use ArrayList. Today is 24 feb 2016, stop kicking .Net 1.1 corps, please.

You can achieve this with LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<ListViewItem> getSortedListView()
{
    ListView lvLocations = new ListView();
    lvLocations.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();

    // Reads CSV file to get required location. 
    // lvGlobalLocations is filled with every location on the system.

    return lvGlobalLocations.Items.Where(item => item.Text == <location name>).OrderBy(x => x.Whatever);
}
```

or use `List.Sort` (yes, generic list has a lot of useful methods):

```
public List<ListViewItem> getSortedListView()
{
    ListView lvLocations = new ListView();
    lvLocations.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();

    // Reads CSV file to get required location. 
    // lvGlobalLocations is filled with every location on the system.

    var list = new List<ListViewItem>(lvGlobalLocations.Items.Where(item => item.Text == <location name>))
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.Whatever.CompareTo(b.Whatever));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: both you and N_tro_P were right in saying I should steer clear of the comparator. The reason I chose yours as the correct answer is simply due to yours was the method that worked. Although I did have to change `lvGlobalLocations.Items.Where` to `lvGlobalLocations.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>.Where` and parse a and b to ints for it to compare correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear it. So good luck, and do not use non-generic collections, even when you work with `object` :)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy, today is is aug 2018 and we are still kicking .net 2 corpse because deploy machine doesn't support anything further!

Comment: @AaA .Net 2 already has generics, so it's relatively Ok. However, I commiserate with you. I can feel your pain. I firstly have read it as `we are still kicking .netcore 2 corpse`, and then I realised that things are much worse...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need that much actually. Lamda's allow for property specification in the sort. Just make sure you are defining your "sub item" or understand the signature of the object.

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(item => item.PropertyToSortBy);
```

If the requirement is to use the comparitor object you must actually use it.

```
var sorted = list.Sort(comparitor);
```

It will use the default sort defined by the object itself. This indicates yet another sort possibility. Have the contained object be `ICompariable`.

Again, I would simply use a lamda expression. This is a trivial sort. Once you have to sort on numerous properties and other processing logic you would consider either a comparitor or putting the sort logic on the object itself.